# Ubuntu 14.04 syslog showing @@@@ for long time period

Tags: syslog

My Ubuntu Server wasn't accessible for a long time, only after restarting the server I could access it again. I have checked the `syslog` file which shows something like `@@@@@@@@@@@@@` from last night until the point I restarted the system. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a bunch of @@@@ in a log file are actually 0X00 bytes, and are due to some sort of crash or failure event where things have gone astray. Typically, the only recovery is a hard reset, as you found in your case. You should examine all the files in `/var/log' to try to gain insight into what happened.